# opendir for usb device /dev/sdb

Tags: linux, usb, device, opendir

I am trying to implement in c program a way to detect if usb is connected or not.
I noticed that when the usb is connected, then the following command from shell will result as following:

```
root:~# ls /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb
```

If usb is disconnected then I get

```
root:~# ls /dev/sdb
ls: /dev/sdb: No such file or directory
```

I therefore assumed that best way to detect usb connected from c program shall be by doing opendir("/dev/sdb"), but the open call is always failed.

Do you have any idea what's best methd to do this detection ?

The main goal, is knowing in run-time program where the udev mounted the harddisk, and where the usb flash drive (if plugged in). 
Thanks,
Ran

Comment: Why don't you use udev ? i think its meant for that.

Comment: thank, I'll read more about udev. Can it tell me also where the device is mounted ?

Answer (score 2):

A) Why your `opendir` call failed? It's easy to understand. Because `/dev/sdb` is not a directory. For me it's hard to understand what you expect, when you try to open device as a directory. If you want to get file list from you usb drive, you need to `mount` the partition (`/dev/sdb1`, `/dev/sdb2`, etc. not the `/dev/sdb`) to some `mount point` (`directory`). And if you mount it successfully, then you can open the directory with your call. Many linux distributions mount usb drive automatically. You can look to your distribution documentation to get the information about automatical mounting of the usb drives.

B) I think it's easy to understand why detecting the usb device this way is bad idea.

=> Different computers have different amount of drives. So on many computers 
`/dev/sdb` - is a hard drive.

=> Asuming you know that there is only one hard drive, the disk naming still can change after computer reboot, so it's possible that after reboot the usb drive will become `sda` and hard drive will become `sdb` (but usually this doesn't happen).

=> Generally, it's not possible to predict a new letter (`sdb` or `sdc` or `sde`).

=> You can't access to the usb devices, that are not usb drives.

=> There are tonns of other problems with such solution.

C) I didn't understand your goal completely, but if you want your program to be make some action if the usb device is plugged in, that the best solution you can do is read about `udev` and the event system of your distribution. If you want to make with your usb device some low level operations, you can read about `libusb`. You can get the general information about usb devices with `lsusb` command which is usually a part of a distributions. You can google for some other infermer commands.

Comment: hi, this is embedded product in which I need the program shall need to know which device is harddisk (as you said most of the time sda - harddisk) and which is usb storage removable device (sdb probably). so to summarize, I need to know where is the harddisk, and where is the usb flash driver device (relevant only if plugged). Thanks, Ran

Comment: udev mount both automatically. Is there some way I can query udev, where it mounted the harddisk and where the usb flash drive ?

Comment: Look in libudev documentation, if you want to query the information with your application. And I found a tutorial that might be helpfull. http://www.signal11.us/oss/udev/      But if you need to make some action on files only on plugging in, that it's better just add a script that does the action in udev rules.

Comment: For embedded system you can use mdev also which is lighter than udev.

Answer (score 0):

The device `/dev/sdb` is not a directory, it's just a device, so you should use a system call like `stat` that will tell you whether a file exists instead of trying to calling `opendir` on it.
Please note that `/dev/sdb` could be any kind of hard drive depending on the setup of your specific system; it is not necessarily a USB drive.

Alternatively, you could execute the `lsusb` utility and parse its output.

Comment: fstat takes fd as its first argument, moreover device file presence doesn't mean USB is connected, specially for embedded system, at times embedded system uses static device files, so fstat is not good idea, am i right ? in my opinion he should go with mdev/udev and lsusb would help framing udev rules.

Comment: Oops, I changed it to stat instead of fstat.  I don't know about these static device files, but even if that is true, the OP can probably avoid using that feature on his machine.  He has explicitly told us that sdb is only present when his USB device is plugged in and he has not said that this needs to be a general solution for all systems.